# Identify female power connector

Tags: identification, connector

How to identify female power connector with 2 pins, 1.00 mm pitch? Is it JST SH connector?

Picture of the connector:

[image]

Comment: Looks like it might be 1.27mm .

Comment: definitely more than 1.0 mm

Comment: "Is it JST SH connector?" [No, it is not](https://media.digikey.com/photos/JST%20Photos/SM02B-SRSS-TB(LF)(SN).jpg).

Comment: @TomCarpenter You are right. Is 1.27mm or 1.25mm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [Molex PicoBlade](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/picoblade) connector.

[image]

Comment: That is 1.25 mm pitch. Strange that it is not the more standard 1.27 mm (0.05"), but should not matter for just two pins, and probably up to 4 or 5 before it would be an issue. But I think most small connectors like this have round pins, and not blades.

Comment: You identified it! Thank you.